# How to find the sum in a multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, windows, eclipse

This code only shows the array in order

Output:
First array
 13 15 55 69 88559

45 22 33 697

5

Second array

299 56

69

```
public class Multidimensional_Arrays { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int firstarray[][]={{13,15 , 55 , 69 , 88559} , {45,22,33,697 } , {5}};
    int secondarray[][]={{299 , 56} , {69}}     
    System.out.println("First array");
    mtd(firstarray);

    System.out.println("Second array");
    mtd(secondarray);
  } 

  public static void mtd(int x[][]){
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
       for (int y=0 ; y<x[i].length; y++) {  
           System.out.print(" "+x[i][y]);
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question, please.

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply!
The problem was that I printed the integer of sum inside the array, not outside of it, and that's why I was getting the strange output.Now that I put it out of the array, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the function to return an integer that is going to be you sum of all elements.
and then you can easily count the sum of the arrays. For example convert your `void mtd(int x[][])` to `int sumOfArray(int x[][])`  and then

```
public static int sumOfArray(int x[][]){
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < x[i].length ; j++) {
            result += x[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

After that you can easily call the function to get the count of these arrays  in your main function

```
System.out.println("First array count: " + sumOfArray(firstarray));

System.out.println("Second array count: " + sumOfArray(secondarray));
```